# Can I use python code output to feed my next step?

Tags: zapier

Let's say I have some python code that calls an API endpoint and creates an object in X app. The successful execution will return the ID of the newly created object.

I would like Zapier to receive the output (returned data) and allow me to use it as `input_data` on a subsequent step.

Possible?

Researching

Answer (score 2):

As per https://zapier.com/help/how-get-started-code-python-zapier/
you have only to explicitly return a dictionary or populate the "output" variable from within your code

```
return {'id': 1234, 'hello': 'world!', 'name': input_data['name']}
```

or

```
output = {'id': 1234, 'hello': 'world!', 'name': input_data['name']}
```

The next Zap step will have id, hello, name as potential input parameters

Comment: Hopefully you mark @Ferdinando Simonetti's response as the answer.